# Truncated/Compact PDF417 Matrix

Tags: java, pdf, barcode, truncated

I'm reading a compact/truncated PDF417 barcode using java and I have the matrices for the start and end pattern for a standard PDF417 barcode:

```
   Start Pattern = 81111113 (ending with a space)
   Stop Pattern = 711311121 (ending with a bar)
```

What I need to find out is the matrix for the Stop Pattern when the barcode is compact/truncated.

I've been Googling it for the past 4 hours and absolutly nothing.

Any help will be greatly apreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider buying ISO/IEC 15438 (http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=43816). Anyway, in compact mode the right row indicators may be omitted and the stop pattern may be reduced to one module width bar (Annex G in ISO/IEC 15438:2001(E)).